# sum involving Riemann zeta function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

In my work arose the following series:
$$g(s) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\log(\zeta(n+2))}{n+2}s^{n}.$$
It has radius of convergence $2$ and converges for $|s| \leq 2$ except at $s = 2$.  I'm wondering, does anyone know any particular explicit values of this function besides $g(0) = \frac{1}{2}\log(\zeta(2))$, e.g., what is $g(1)$, $g(-1)$, or $g(-2)$?  Also, does it have meromorphic continuation, and what is its behavior at the singularity $s = 2$?

Comment: Can you use $\log\zeta(n+2)\approx 1/2^{n+2}$, subtract off that explicit contribution, then the same with the $1/3^{n+2}$ term, etc.?